# How can I explain a word used in a previous sentence?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english, commas, this-that

I am defining a "thing" with an adjective.

Example:

> X is a small y.

Then I want to give a clean and simple explanation for the adjective `small` --because it can mean several things and I want to make it clear.

So I'd like to continue the sentence with something like:

> .. small y. What "small" here means is ...

**My question:**

- What is the correct way to continue with that second sentence in English?

Can I say:

1. `What "small" here means is, that, X [verb (is, doesn't etc)] ..` or;
2. `What "small" here means is X [verb (is, doesn't etc)] ..`

By correct, I mean, should I use `that`? Should I use a comma?

Thank you.

Comment: X is a small y, small in this context meaning...

Comment: @Ste, Shouldn't it be *"X is a small Y. 'Small' in this context means..."*?

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Your suggestion is perfectly valid if you wish to have two distinct sentences.  However, I feel that it flows better as two parts, separated with a comma.  Quotation marks optional.

Comment: If you question essentially is whether *that* is needed or not, then the answer is that it **can** be dropped. All else is writing advice/ proof-reading.

Comment: For sentences like the ones you proposed, I would use "that" but without commas.  For the sake of brevity, I often avoid "what" and "is" by writing "Here 'small' means that X ...."  Ste's suggestion to combine the two sentences into one works as long as the resulting sentence is not too long or convoluted; so it's fine with "X is a small y" but it might become awkward if that part were replaced with something long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two examples are focusing on the word "that":

> What "small" here means is, that, ...
>
> What "small" here means is ...

You could use "that" but it shouldn't have the commas and I much prefer it without the "that".

But I think the bigger problem is the order of "here" and "means":

> What "small" means here is...

You could also remove "what":

> "Small", here, means...

Which gives us these final examples:

> X is a small Y. What "small" means here is less than 30 inches.
>
> X is a small Y. "Small", here, means less than 30 inches.

Other options:

> X is a small Y. "Small" means less than 30 inches.
>
> X is a small Y ("small" meaning less than 30 inches).
>
> X is a small Y. "Small" in this context means "less than 30 inches."

Comment: Other options would be *By "small", I mean less than 30 inches*; or *"Small" here means that it is less than 30 inches*.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn’t it look and feel better if “ small here means less than 30 inches” was as an “aside” in parenthesis? Or maybe that’s just off the wall.